# Android ==> ant and proguard?

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, build.xml

I am getting the following error while obfuscating my application.
How can i define the output jar in my build.xml?

```
 [java] Shrinking...
 [java] java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
 [java]     at proguard.shrink.Shrinker.execute(Shrinker.java:148)
 [java]     at proguard.ProGuard.shrink(ProGuard.java:294)
 [java]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:100)
 [java]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:499)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial [here](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/07/optimizing-obfuscating-and-shrinking.html) has never gone wrong for me.

Comment: I have tried it, it doesn't work:
BUILD FAILED
/Users/aryan/Desktop/MyApp/build.xml:49: taskdef class com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found

Comment: thanks, i finally figured out what the problem was.
I specified the sdk location manually instead of reading from local.properties   <property name="sdk.dir" value="/Platforms/android.platform" />

Answer (score 8):

1. Use Android SDK Tools revision 8 or later
2. If you do not have build.xml for your project,    run command like this in some empty directory 
   `android create project --name <Your Project Name> --package <Your Company Name> --target 7 --path . --activity dummy` Find build.xml which you can copy to root directory of the project.
3. In default.properties add reference to proguard settings (proguard.config=proguard.cfg)
4. **Turn off android:debuggable in application manifest.**
5. Run 'ant release' command

You should find directory called ./bin/proguard and ./bin/-release.apk. You can find [more details here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html).

Comment: I'm going to reiterate your point #4 "Turn off android:debuggable in application manifest."  ProGuard does not run at all if debuggable is true!!