# The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?

Tags: android, android-build

I am trying to build a release APK file from ant and this is what i m getting in my console

```
D:\AndroidSDK\android-sdk_r18-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:595: The following error occurred while executing this line:D:\AndroidSDK\android-sdk_r18windows\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:864: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
```

What is this error and how can i resolve it..M using the latest SDK(API-17) with Revision 21.1
All java_home,Ant_home are set

Comment: Help me guys..i m stuck

Comment: Looks like a ProGuard issue. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/q/3400264/1321873 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10934436/1321873

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohkk I got the answer myself..There was a problem in the Manifest file on the jar project which i was using as a library..The created the lib project,Updated it and referenced it to my main code .As in this LInk..and it worked:-)
[here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html)

Answer (score 20):

For library projects, I needed to add `-dontshrink` option to proguard config file - proguard was shrinking ALL my classes.

Answer (score 2):

When using gradle build system, there is no need to modify `proguard-rules.pro`.

Just inside specified `buildType` define `minifyEnabled false`. Example:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this helps but it does even though I build a debug build.

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't the top answer.