# Error:Gradle: > java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?

Tags: android, gradle

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':smartupdate:shri
>   nkDebugAndroidTestMultiDexComponents'.
>   java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?

What's wrong ? please help me.very thanks.

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDE 14

Comment: There is a problem with your proguard file. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869315/the-output-jar-is-empty-did-you-specify-the-proper-keep-options?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I annotated my subproject build.gradle, as follows. It works well:

```
defaultConfig {

    ........

    //multiDexEnabled = true

}
```